# Will_paginate gives 'unusual' result on count when using group clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Using Rails3 and will_paginate 3.0.2 and seeing an unusual issue:

> Rating.paginate(:page => 1).count

=> 3

BUT if I add the group clause:

> Rating.paginate(:page => 1, :group => "drill_id").count

**=> {3=>2, 4=>1}**

The closest google result I found was this:
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/167

But this doesnt seem to be the exact same issue.Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, this is killing me too!

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a grouped result from `#count`. It's basically a count of `Rating` per `drill_id`. The keys of the result hash are `drill_id`s with their corresponding values being the count of `Rating`s for this `drill_id`. See [AR::Calculations#count](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) for details.

You want to know how many `drill_id`s there are between all your `Rating`s instead? Choose one:

- **Fix the query**

  `Rating.select('DISTINCT drill_id').count`
- **Count the keys**

  `Rating.paginate(page: 1, group: 'drill_id').keys.count`